# Magento 2 - Filterable option not appearing

Tags: magento2

I've created an attribute and need to show in Layered Navigation on product listing page, but I can't find the **Use in Layered Navigation** option.

I've searched and followed the steps but couldn't find that option in admin under storefront properties.
Please guide me in this,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually that option is stored here : [image]

> Stores -> Attributes -> Product -> Storefront Properties

What magento 2 version are you using ? Did you created attribute manually or programaticlly ?